# Why does JS call `toString` method when object is added to a number

Tags: javascript

I know that when JS tries to represent an object as primitive, it calls `valueOf` method on an object. But today I found out that it also calls `toString()` method in the same situation:

```
var o = {};
o.toString = function() {return 1};
1+ o; // 2
```

Why? If I add `valueOf` method then `toString` is not called.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

it all depends on the Hint. 
when you use `1 + o` it is a number Hint because of the `+` operand so it would definitely use `valueOf` before `toString`.

If the hint is String, then `toString` is used before `valueOf`. for example try `["o",o].join("=")`

All together would be:

```
var o = {};
o.toString = function() {return 1};
o.valueOf= function(){return 2};
1 + o; // 1+2=3 ==> it takes valueOf value
["o",o].join("") //o1 ==> it takes toString value
```

Comment: Thanks for the head up about the hint. It is definitely hinted as a Number. I edited my own answer thanks to yours..

Comment: thanks, how to determine what is hint? what types of hints exist? Is hint connected to `+` operator?

Comment: @Maximus 
the hint is simply a type clue for JS to perform its action. 
In our context only one of the two types (String, Number) would be used. 
In JS there are 6 Types (undefined, null, string, number, object, boolean). 
in our case Yes + Operator gives a hint to JS engine to act with this value as a number and use method valueOf() before toString()

Comment: @YehiaAwad, I see, thanks a lot for your explanation. As I understand, every mathematical operator uses a hint, correct? Is hint only limited to mathematical operators?

Comment: @Maximus Correct all mathematical operands uses a hint in our case.
No, hint is not limited to mathematical operators only as explained in my example join("") method pushes JS engine to use a string hint rather than number one :)

Answer (score 10):

I suppose the explanation lies in 8.6.2.6 chapter of [ECMA-262 specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%201st%20edition,%20June%201997.pdf):

> 8.6.2.6 [DefaultValue]

[...]

When the [[DefaultValue]] method of O is called with **hint Number**, the following steps are taken:

1. **Call the [[Get]] method of object O with argument "valueOf".**
2. **If Result(1) is not an object, go to step 5.**
3. Call the [[Call]] method of Result(1), with O as the this value and an empty argument list.
4. If Result(3) is a primitive value, return Result(3).
5. **Call the [[Get]] method of object O with argument "toString".**
6. If Result(5) is not an object, go to step 9.
7. Call the [[Call]] method of Result(5), with O as the this value and an empty argument list.
8. If Result(7) is a primitive value, return Result(7).
9. Generate a runtime error.
   When the [[DefaultValue]] method of O is called with no hint, then it behaves as if the hint were Number,
   unless O is a Date object (see section 15.9), in which case it behaves as if the hint were String.

Since your object doesn't implement valueOf, toString is used.

Comment: That's right, but I think it worth to mention also **11.6.1 The addition operator ( + )**, that says 7. **If Type(Result(5)) is String or Type(Result(6)) is String, go to step 12.**, where Result(5) is **Call ToPrimitive(Result(2)).**. This is why sum needs to access default value, and it has different behavior basing on what's the type of default value

Answer (score 5):

**TL;DR**

When ToPrimitive is called with no `hint` it acts as if the hint was `number`. That defines methods to be called: first `valueOf` then `toString`. If you haven't defined your own `valueOf` it will call `Object.prototype.valueOf` that returns this.

BTW in modern browsers you can be more specific about it

```
const a = {
   [Symbol.toPrimitive]: function(hint) {
       console.log(hint);
       return {
          'default': 1,
          'number': 2,
          'string': 'three'
       }[hint]
   }
}

console.log(a + 1); //default, 2
console.log(+a + 1); //number, 3
console.log(`${a} + one`); //string, three + one
```

Long read:

1. [Addition](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/2016/#sec-addition-operator-plus)
2. [ToPrimitive](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/2016/#sec-toprimitive)